# Entity Framework Core realtime data update

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework-core, devexpress, .net-6.0

In `WinForms`, using the `Entity Framework Core 7`, I connect the `Postgresql` database table and display it in the `DevExpress` `GridControl.DataView` table. Is it possible to update data in a table in real time? so that changes in the database table are immediately displayed in `GridControl.DataView`?

Now I have created a table class, a database connection context and a form with data output to the table. But the data in the table is not updated in real time.

```
internal class sl_doc
{
    [Key]
    public Guid doc_code { get; set; }
    public string? doc_info { get; set; }
}
```

```
internal class ApplicationContext : DbContext
{                       
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql("Host=localhost;Port=5432;Database=test;Username=postgres;Password=test");
    }
    public DbSet<sl_doc> sl_doc { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

```
ApplicationContext db;
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
 
    db = new ApplicationContext();
    db.sl_doc.Load(); 
    gridControl1.DataSource = db.sl_doc.Local.ToBindingList();
}
```